# C# WPF Images not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In my code, I have 3 images that are empty and then I set the source in the code behind. The relative path I'm giving them is the right one but the images are not displaying anyway. I got no clue how to fix this.

Xaml

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="44,135,433,248" BorderBrush="#FF000000">
  <Image x:Name="imageHelmet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="-1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" MouseEnter="helmet_MouseEnter"/>
</Border>
```

Behind

```
string source = @"..\..\..\Images\" + piece.Link;
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.UriSource = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative);
bmp.EndInit();
imageChestplate.Source = bmp;
```

This is just one of them, but the rest are the same.

Comment: What's the height and width of your window that contains the border and image?

Answer (score 0):

The image is likely hidden due to the margin of the border, at least that's what I saw when I attempted to recreate your problem.

Here, the `Margin` Property of the `Border` is set to `44,135,433,248`. This means that there is a margin of 433 on the right side, and 248 on the bottom.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="44,135,433,248" BorderBrush="#FF000000">
```

The edge of the window counts as something getting within the margin, so if the window is too small, it will not leave enough space for the margin, and as such the margin will be pushed over the image, hiding it.

To remedy this situation, change the right and bottom values in the margin to `0`, and set the `Border`'s `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`, and `VerticalAlignment` to `Top`.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" Margin="44,135,0,0" BorderBrush="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image x:Name="imageHelmet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="-1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" MouseEnter="helmet_MouseEnter"/>
</Border>
```

This way, there's no margin on the right and bottom sides to get pushed over the image, and the alignment makes it so the left and top alignments are used correctly.